# Notificação de sinalizadores incorreta

Tags: bug, status-nãorepro, notificações

A notificação laranja indica que tem um sinalizador na fila para eu analisar, mas quando acesso a fila ela está vazia:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Já vi algo semelhante acontecer aqui no meta, com a notificação de edições sugeridas: a notificação marrom dizia haver itens na fila, mas ela estava vazia.

**Seriam minhas próprias sugestões de edição, que eu havia acabado de fazer quando notei o problema?**

---

Confirmando, minhas próprias sugestões de edição vazam notificações, ao menos aqui no meta:

[image: Captura de Tela]

Comment: Confirmo que ocorreu comigo. Achei que poderia ser que alguém tivesse analisado nesse exato momento.

Comment: Acho que não, @bigown. Ontem no meta vi isso durar por um bom tempo.

Comment: Aparentemente, esse número mostra o **total** de flags aguardando moderação, **sem subtrair** desse total aquelas que você já analisou. Trata-se de um bug, com certeza.

Comment: Está acontecendo isso comigo há alguns dias (30/07/2014)

Comment: Como não existe mais o indicador de sinalizadores (exceto para moderadores), acho que você está falando **[disto aqui](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1282/contador-de-sugest%C3%B5es-de-edi%C3%A7%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1-incoerente)**, @carlosrafaelgn.

Comment: @bfavaretto Sim! Realmente esse é o caso. O meu fica marcando `10` ou `11`, mas não há absolutamente nada na fila (0 Votos para Fechar, 0 Autoavaliação do site....) :/

Comment: Então @carlosrafaelgn, é que o indicador mostra o total de itens pendentes, incluindo os que você já analisou (faltam análises de outros usuários para eles deixarem de ser contabilizados). Eu também não gosto desse comportamento, mas disseram que vai ficar assim...

Comment: Ahhhhhhh!!! Agora entendi! "pendente" no sentido de que algo que eu analisei foi encaminhado para outras pessoas analisarem, mas elas ainda não o fizeram! :)